# django-shop vs Satchless?

Tags: django, paypal, e-commerce, shopping-cart

Can anyone compare these two e-commerce frameworks?

I found [this link](http://www.readncode.com/blog/the-state-of-ecommerce-in-django/), but I am not sure how outdated it might be. It mentioned that Satchless was still in the early stage. And at least according to [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6238961/is-django-shop-ready-for-production) from last year, django-shop was not production ready. Is it production ready now?

What I need is actually quite simple. I only need a B2C website (i.e. only me selling products to customers). The desired features include anonymous checkout, shipping cost + tax calculable, friendly products returning interface, paypal support. The code is hopefully easy to read and customizable (thus I will avoid Satchmo)

For Satchless: is it based on Satchmo, or a rewrite?

For django-shop: I noticed there is a giant [ecosystem](https://www.django-shop.org/en/ecosystem/) for django-shop. It implies that django-shop is highly customizable, but that might also imply inconsistent code design and implementation quality. And it looks like even paypal checkout needs a 3rd party extension?

Thanks again, I appreciate all your input.

Comment: django-shop seems to match your needs but the doc is lacking a bit

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Satchless isn't a rewrite of Satchmo, it's name is simply a reaction to the perceived poor quality of Satchmo's codebase. It's designed to be very minimal, but extensible. It's changed a fair bit over the last couple of years, so might not be a particularly stable platform choice (ie it's likely the API will continue to change in big ways).

There's also Oscar, which is more opinionated and feature-rich, but still designed to be extensible: https://github.com/tangentlabs/django-oscar

Disclaimer: I've worked with the Satchless guys (not on Satchless itself) and on Oscar directly.

Comment: Hi Andrew, thanks for the recommendation. Is Oscar an out-of-box solution? like do I have to write my own templates from scratch, or there are enough examples from the source code I can use directly? I realize that I need to write templates fro django-shop...

Comment: The original plan for Oscar was for it to not be an out-of-the-box solution, but it's been transitioning towards providing something more complete. The default templates are based on Bootstrap. The sandbox site is basically what you get as a starting point: http://latest.oscarcommerce.com/

Answer (score 0):

You requirements sound like [Mezzanine](http://mezzanine.jupo.org/) + [Cartridge](http://cartridge.jupo.org/) would be a better solution for you.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Can you explain a bit why, and why django-shop and Satchless aren't as good?